# How to open ports on a vps server by IPv4 mapping?

Tags: linux, debian, vps

I'm new to VPS, and I chose vps.me(free version) for hosting a game server. The game server needs the ports 28760, 28763 and 28764 to be open. I read their documentation and said I must use IPv4 mapping but they never explained how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You VPS shares a single IPv4 address with others. You can't get specific ports facing the Internet as a whole. The help from the provider shows how to make port mappings in the help for [What is IPv4 port mapping?](http://www.vps.me/kb/free-vps/what-is-ipv4-mapping)

Comment: @Brian so how to open the ports? I can't find it, i tried many iptables commands and none worked. Is it possible to portforward using iptables?

Comment: @Brian I've tried it but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the documentation, the procedure is pretty straight forward. But it is *not* done through iptables on the VPC itself. That will come in to play *after* you've gotten traffic to the VPC itself.

1. Log in to your vms.me account, not the VPS.
2. In that interface there should be a *My Servers* tab. Go there.
3. Choose IPv4 mapping.
4. Select the external port you want to be visible (Source Port).
5. Select the VPS port you want that traffic sent to (Destination Port).
6. Click 'Add Port'.

The traffic should be showing up on your VPC at that point.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But can you give an example, If I want to open port 28760, what should I write on Source port and Destination port?

Comment: Also, when I entered 28760 in Souce port and a random port on Destination port, it says : "This port is already taken by someone. Please choose another one."

Comment: @HGSur I think you have your ports swapped. 'Source' is the externally visible one, and it looks like someone else has camped 28760. Destination should always be 28760, as that is where your game-server is listening on your actual VPS.

Comment: so i have to type 28760 in destination port and a random port on Source port?

Comment: @HGSur That is correct.